# Ubuntu 16.10 "Search for files" in Gnome useless

Tags: gnome, 16.10, search

The search for files application in Ubuntu 16.10 (Gnome) is quite useless. It searches and finds files & folders successfully, but it won't open anything in the search results (Or do anything about them, for that matter): Double clicking on the files, right clicking and selecting "open" or "open with" or "open containing folder" doesn't do anything at all. No error, no result, no opened files, anything.

What is the point of this? Is this a bug? Alternatively, it there is a better search application that actually does what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Exactly what command or application are you running?

Comment: The default? I just type "search"  in the "Activities" view in gnome, and that is what pops up. "About"  for that application indicates it is called "Search for files..." version 3.6.0-2

Comment: I'm trying to duplicate what you are seeing.  There isn't an **Activities** in the default Ubuntu installation.  I installed **Gnome** and set it as the login and see an Activities menu.  I'm assuming this is what you are referring to.  When clicking on Activities, I see a **Type to search** box.    That items works.  Is that what you are referring to?  I don't see a **Search for Files** option.  I always use Unity instead of Gnome.  If you can tell me how to get to the **Search for Files** that you are having problems with, I'm sure I can assist in it's usage or give you and alternative.

Comment: @L.D.James I think he's thinking of the program installed by tracker-gui.

Comment: @JeremyBicha Thanks for the info.  I installed the **tracker-gui** app.  It doesn't show an **Activities** clickable option to type in a search... at least I can't find one.  Also the user keep making references  **gnome**.  So it would appear from all his text that he's using **gnome** rather than **Unity**.  The **gnome** interface has something similar to the **Ubuntu Dash Search** in **Unity**.  It's called **Activities**.

Comment: @user53330 You have something installed on your system that is different from a distribution default.  We'll have to know what you have installed do assist you with how to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GNOME 3 search bar with no results](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976172/gnome-3-search-bar-with-no-results)